# Jquery regex format yyy-mm-dd

Tags: jquery, regex

What is the regex for YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: why use regex? just do `new Date()`, pass in the value you have and check if it got parsed correctly; your regex won't check for stuff like 2012-02-30 or 2011-02-29

Comment: `/^\d{4}-[0-1]((?<=1)[12]|(?<!1)[1-9])-[0-3]((?<=[0-2])[0-9]|(?<=3)[01])$/`

Answer (score 4):

Well, depends on how anal you want to be about it.

A number is `[0-9]`, so you could just do `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`.

But months only go from 01 to 12, so you could do `[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-[0-9]{2}`.

Then again, dates only go from 01 to 31, so you could do `[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[012])`.

You could even restrict years if you wanted (for example dates of birth can reasonably be restricted to 1900+).

Comment: +1 And I'm quite sure you could write a meter long regex to check the day range and to check if the year is a leap year :-)

Comment: I realise "how anal you want to be about it" sounds like I might be trying to be rude - I'm not, no offense meant!

Answer (score 1):

well, http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/dateyyyymmdd.html first google result to *regex date yyyymmdd*

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```